# What new iPhone App that lets you maintain a single list, star items and sort them?

Tags: iphone, applications

There was a new iPhone app released recently but I can't recall its name. It had some very simple features:

- Keep a single list of things
- Star items
- Sort those items so that stars rose to the top

What was its name? The app in question is not 1list.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, it was [LittleList](http://thrsn.com/littlelist/)

Answer (score 0):

I was guessing it was **[Wunderlist](http://www.6wunderkinder.com/wunderlist-iphone/)**.